# Determine time to open .odt document

Tags: bash, libreoffice

I am trying to see how long it takes to open a document.

The reason is that it seems faster from a terminal than when used as a panel item.

I need to kill the process.

killall soffice-bin does not work.

```
time /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/swriter --nologo  /home/andy/Documents/Blank.odt
sleep 1
# killall ??
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to locate the pid(s) for Libreoffice.

Try:

```
ps -ef|grep libreoffice
```

You should now have the process id numbers, you can then

```
kill -9 pid1 pid2 ..
```

Another option is you can try my kkill, or kkiller
[kkill & kkiller](https://github.com/giorgossaridakis/kkill)

```
kkill libreoffice
```

will kill all instances. kkiller is a daemon, you can have it kill the process immediately, on detection.

**update: I've added rpid (or my version of pidof) to the git. With it, it's possible to locate pids, no additional information, without exact name search, a string within a string.**

Answer (score 1):

#!/bin/bash

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
# See how long it takes to open a document Help from tkn.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

logfile="/home/andy/Downloads/log.txt"
swriter="/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/swriter --nologo  /home/andy/Documents/Blank.odt"

( time $swriter & sleep 2 && pkill soffice.bin ) 2>"$logfile"
```